# Using open ID with Google app engine

Tags: java, authentication, openid, federated

I have an app running on Google app engine.  I want to change the sign-in from using google, to using open id, in Java.

So, I tried following this guide:

http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/openid.html

1. I changed the authentication to federated login on the application settings dashboard.
2. I put this in the web.xml:

   ```
   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>LoginRequiredServlet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>XXXXXX.server.LoginRequiredServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>LoginRequiredServlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/_ah/login_required</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   ```
3. I created a class called LoginRequiredServlet, with the code that is on the above link.    I renamed their class OpenIdDemoServlet to LoginRequiredServlet.
4. I redeployed.  Upon going to my landing page, it only takes me a google login page.  What exactly do I have to do to so it can show a few links to other OpenID providers?

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, did you have any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I'm quoting http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/openid.html except that I have changed the class name from OpenIdDemoServlet to LoginRequiredServlet.

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LoginRequiredServlet extends HttpServlet {

```
private static final Map<String, String> openIdProviders;
static {
    openIdProviders = new HashMap<String, String>();
    openIdProviders.put("Google", "google.com/accounts/o8/id");
    openIdProviders.put("Yahoo", "yahoo.com");
    openIdProviders.put("MySpace", "myspace.com");
    openIdProviders.put("AOL", "aol.com");
    openIdProviders.put("MyOpenId.com", "myopenid.com");
}

@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {
    UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
    User user = userService.getCurrentUser(); // or req.getUserPrincipal()
    Set<String> attributes = new HashSet();

    resp.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();

    if (user != null) {
        out.println("Hello <i>" + user.getNickname() + "</i>!");
        out.println("[<a href=\""
                + userService.createLogoutURL(req.getRequestURI())
                + "\">sign out</a>]");
    } else {
        out.println("Hello world! Sign in at: ");
        for (String providerName : openIdProviders.keySet()) {
            String providerUrl = openIdProviders.get(providerName);
            String loginUrl = userService.createLoginURL(req
                    .getRequestURI(), null, providerUrl, attributes);
            out.println("[<a href=\"" + loginUrl + "\">" + providerName + "</a>] ");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Also update your web.xml so as to force logging in. the code below will force logging for 
all urls on the website.